# Aggregator - Convert Array Released Object to JMS Text Message

Tags: spring-integration

**Issue:** 
The spring integration aggregator releases an aggregated message as a array list. How would I send the aggregated response as a single jms message? Do I need to use a transformer first?

Aggregator:

```
<aggregator 
id="myAgg" 
input-channel="jmsInChannel"
output-channel="outputChannel" 
discard-channel="discardChannel"
ref="myAggBean" 
method="combineRespones"
expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
correlation-strategy-expression="#xpath(payload, '/test/name')"
release-strategy="myAggBean"
release-strategy-method="canRelease"
send-partial-result-on-expiry="false"
send-timeout="5000"
group-timeout="20000"/>
```

Output Channel:

```
    <channel id="outputChannel">
    <int:queue/>
</channel>
```

Outbound Adapter:

```
    <jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="outputChannel"
    id="jmsOut"
    destination="outboundQueue"/>
```

**UPDATE 1**: - Originally this post has the following error but this was due to my config releasing the message to the wrong queue.

**Error:**
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: unsupported payload type [java.util.ArrayList]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear

- if you want the released messages to be sent as individual text messages to JMS, add `<splitter/>` between the aggregator and outbound channel adapter.
- if you want the list to be sent as a single message, you will need a transformer of some kind to format it the way you want.

Comment: Ya I want to send the aggregated message as a single message. I will use a transformer. I thought transformer for object-to-string would be all I need to pass to a the outbound adapter but it still keeps it in object form in the queue.

Comment: Updated the question for clarity for future reference.